# how to show the syntax of a shortcode

Tags: shortcode

I want to show the syntax in some posts about how to run a shortcode. I mean, something like this [myshortcode] but without running it, is that possible?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you use double brackets, [WordPress will not execute the shortcode but just display it with single brackets](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.2/wp-includes/shortcodes.php#L196). So `[[gallery]]` becomes *[gallery]* in your post.

Comment: Didn't know that! Excellent tip

Comment: You learn something new every day +1

Comment: Seriously good tip! Never knew you could do this +1

Comment: If you really like this answer, don't forget to upvote the question too!

Comment: Depending on the plugin, doesn't always work. Eg dowsn't work for the Audio PLayer plugin. It's probably using a non-standard technique for finding the embed codes. Sigh.

Comment: While this (using double brackets) seems to work with simple shortcodes, I'm having trouble getting it to work with ones of this type:  [foo]Hello![/foo].  any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing the first `[` with `&#091;` in the Source editor tab instead of the Visual tab

Comment: Thanks but does't works, any new idea?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a moron. The html entity for that char is &#091; Put that in the Source tab.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use triple brackets [[[gallery]]] but I do not kwow why

Comment: Can you explain this? Looks more like a comment than an answer.