# Prevent wordpress from rendering shortcode in post

Tags: shortcode

Suppose I have a `[list]` shortcode. I want to have a post explaining how to use shortcodes (docs for my theme). How can I have a header like

> `[list type="arrow"] Shortcode Tag`

Currently wordpress will mess it up converting `[list type="arrow"]` into invalid HTML

Comment: Sidenote: [shortcode madness: replacing basic HTML](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2011/05/02/dealing-with-shortcode-madness)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to show the syntaxis of a shortcode](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16991/how-to-show-the-syntaxis-of-a-shortcode)

Comment: I think the argument is valid. I think one of the reasons why shortcode is simpler for non developers is its better documented in themes and more visible in the editors. WordPress shld add a hook for its editors to allow theme developers to add CSS Classes into the WordPress editor for users to select/view

Comment: This is already possible, see [my answer with a complete example](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3882/can-i-add-a-custom-format-to-the-format-option-in-the-text-panel/3884#3884).

Answer (score 5):

This is very similar to [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16991/how-to-show-the-syntaxis-of-a-shortcode) where Jan had given us all a great lesson :)

> just use double brackets, WordPress
> will not execute the shortcode but
> just display it with single brackets.

so your header would be `[[list type="arrow"]]`